# Local swf files not working in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash

When i open an swf file, Google Chrome downloads it, when it's already downloaded.
And then says "this kind of file can harm your computer", and it just wont play it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a sysadmin and today a user brought this to my attention. It seems that Chrome no longer supports the direct opening of these file types. Make sure you have the relevant adobe flash version installed and then use IE11 or Firefox. For more info see here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=767342

Mike

Answer (score -1):

Imbed the swf files in HTML and then load the html page. Note that you wont be able to directly access the HTML page, put the html folder structure in local tomcat and then access the content and obviously enable the flash player on chrome.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="CaptivateContent">&nbsp;
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var so = new SWFObject("viewer.swf", "Captivate", "1025", "810", "10", "#CCCCCC");    //change the swf file name
  so.addParam("quality", "high");
  so.addParam("name", "Captivate");
  so.addParam("id", "Captivate");
  so.addParam("wmode", "window");
  so.addParam("bgcolor","#f5f4f1");
  so.addParam("menu", "false");
  so.addParam("AllowScriptAccess","always");
  so.addVariable("variable1", "value1");
  so.setAttribute("redirectUrl", "http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash");
  so.write("CaptivateContent");
 </script>
      

 <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('Captivate').focus();
  document.Captivate.focus();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```